# Angles between equally nullifying vectors.

Tags: vectors

**Q.** The vectors **P**,**Q** and **R** are such that |**P**|=|**Q**|, |**R**|=$\sqrt{2}$|**P**| and **P+Q+R**=$0$. The angles between **P** and **Q**,**Q** and **R**, **P** and **R** are respectively:

a)90,135,135

b)90,45,45

c)45,90,90

d)45,135,135

My text marks the answer as 'a'. But isn't 'b' right too. In case of 'a' we have three vectors pointing radially outward from a common origin, whereas in the case of 'b' we have three vectors forming an isosceles, right triangle with **'R'** as the hypotenuse with head and tail connection forming a equilibrium vector triangle.

Am I wrong somewhere?

[image]

Comment: The angle between -Q and R is 45 degrees, and the angle between P and -R is 45 degrees.

Comment: user84413- Relative to the answer provided by my textbook your claim can be marked valid, but we are provided the freedom to choose the direction of the vectors, so can't we say that Angle(Q,R) is 45 degrees and Angle(P,R) is 45 degrees.

Comment: If you shift the vectors so they have the same initial point, you will see that the angle between P and R is 135 degrees, as is the angle between Q and R.

Comment: oh yes brilliant user84413. That's the perfect answer. I had been marking the angles the wrong way. I shouldn't have taken the angle from tail to head. Do post the comment as an answer, so that I can upvote the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle between -Q and R is 45 degrees, and the angle between P and -R is 45 degrees.

If you shift the vectors so they have the same initial point, you will see that the angle between P and R is 135 degrees, as is the angle between Q and R.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that b is correct, and that $P$ is not the zero vector. We know that $P + Q + R = 0$, so let's dot both sides with $P$. We get $P \cdot P + Q \cdot P + R \cdot P = 0 \cdot P = 0$. Since the angle between $P$ and $Q$ is 90 degrees, the dot product is zero. $P \cdot P$ is definitely positive. Lastly, $P \cdot R$ is positive. To see the last claim, $\theta_{P,R} = 45 = \arccos (\frac{P \cdot R}{|P||R|})$. From there you can easily show that $P \cdot R$ is positive. Thus you'd have a positive number equaling zero, which isn't possible.

Comment: blakeoft - Your answer felt partially convincing to me. But isn't it possible diagrammatically as in the above picture (added in the question).

Comment: blakeoft - thanks for your answer, I realized that in case of the diagram I had been making a schoolboy error.